# How does kubernetes do service address to endpoint pod address translation? use kube-proxy and NAT?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networking

I deployed a service `myservice` to the k8s cluster. Using `kubectl describe serivce ...`, I can find that the service ip is `172.20.127.114` . At the same time, the service endpoint is `10.34.188.30:5000,10.34.89.157:5000`. How does Kubernetes handle service address to endpoint address translation? Does `kube-proxy` handle the NAT?  Which linux module does `kube-proxy` use to handle NAT?

```
kubectl describe service myservice                                     

Name:              myservice
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=myservice
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=myservice
Annotations:       argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: 3
Selector:          app=myservice
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                172.20.127.114
IPs:               172.20.127.114
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.34.188.30:5000,10.34.89.157:5000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

`iptables` is used for setting node firewall rules. My understanding is that `iptables` does not do NAT.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you.

##### Pod to Pod communication

- No built-in solution
- Expects you to implement a networking solution
- But impose fundamental requirements on any implementation to be pluggable
  into Kubernetes

###### K8s requirements of CNI Plugins

- Every Pod gets its unique IP address
- Pods on the same Node can Communicate with that IP address
- Pods on different Node can Communicate with that IP address **without NAT**
  (Network Address Translation)

---

##### Kubernetes Networking Model

- All nodes must be able to reach each other, **without NAT**
- All pods must be able to reach each other, **without NAT**
- Pods and nodes must be able to reach each other, **without NAT**
- Each pod is aware of its IP address (**no NAT**)
- Pod IP addresses are assigned by the network implementation

---

##### Summary

- The "pod-to-pod network" or "pod network":

  - Provides communication between pods and nodes
  - Is generally implemented with CNI plugins
- The "pod-to-service network":

  - Provides internal communication and load balancing
  - Is generally implemented with `kube-proxy`
- Network policies:

  - Provide firewalling and isolation
  - Can be bundled with the "pod network" or provided by another component
- Inbound traffic can be handled by multiple components:

  - Something like kube-proxy (for NodePort services)
  - Load balancers (ideally, connected to the pod network)
- It is possible to use multiple pod networks in parallel (with "meta-plugins" like CNI-Genie or Multus)

---

##### Useful Links

- [How CNI works?](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#how-cni-plugins-implement-it)
- [DNS in Kubernetes](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#dns-in-kubernetes)
- [How requests are forwarded from Service to Pod](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#how-requests-are-forwarded-from-service-to-pod)

Comment: thanks for answering the question!  Does kubernetes cluster do DNAT for requests to ClusterIP?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on type of service being used for ClusterIP from within the cluster are never source NAT'd.  More details are [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/)